# How do I reset my search index?

Tags: search-results

I have deleted a document from my library (from the recycling bin as well) but when I search for it, it does still show up so I've been told to reset my search index but I'm not sure how to do this?

Comment: What version of sharepoint (you should add the tag)?

Answer (score 1):

**Central Administration** -> **Application Management** -> **Manage Service Applications** -> **(Your Search Service Application)**

From here, on the left, **Crawling** -> **Index Reset**.

Rather than reset your entire index, you can use **Search Result Removal** under the **Queries and Results** category. However, this will also write an exclusion rule to future crawls to ignore the document you're removing from the search results, so if you're just removing a single document, you can use this to immediately cull the result and then remove the exclusion so that future documents at that address won't be excluded (for example, if a document was inadvertently published prematurely).

Answer (score 0):

The search index is reset in Central Administration, specifically in the Search Administration section.